Does the 'sonic tank' exist outside Dune II?
Is there a mention of the Atreides' sonic tank (Atreides unit in Dune II real-time strategy video game) in any of Frank Herbert's Dune novels or Brian Herbert's prequels and sequels?
I'm aware that the Atreides did develop secret sonic weapons in the Lynch Dune film, albeit more for personal use, like handguns, and not in the tank size.


I don't think this is ever mentioned, and is probably an invention of the game for gameplay-purposes. Sonic Tanks and weaponry do reappear in the later Command & Conquer games made by the same studio that created Dune 2.

I can't speak to the Brian Herbert novels, but in the original 6 there's no mention of sonic tanks (unless they're suddenly showing up in the back half of Chapterhouse, which I am still reading).

@Sofistication - You definitely want to post that as an answer. And for the record, no, they don't magically turn up at the end of Chapterhouse :-)

I don't recall any tanks based on it, but there was the idea of sonic weaponry in the David Lynch Dune movie from the 80's. I wouldn't necessarily recommend it though. The font on the game's box art looks somewhat like the font from the movie title, and the game would have been after the film came out.

If you haven't played https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_II , it was one of the early great resource-control games.  Sure it's dated, but really worth a look to see where all those other games came from.

similar weapons exist IRL, if that's what you're asking. But they are means as non-lethal weapons for crowd control and are usually mounted on trucks rather than tracked vehicles.

Ah, yes, green meadows and trees, exactly the landscape one expects from Dune!

I think it must be the "Green Hill Zone"...

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica that’s the picture for the promotional brochures, most likely made on Caladan

I haven't read the Brian Herbert books so I can't speak of them, but the sonic tanks never appear in the original six book written by Frank Herbert.
user25730 (in the comments of this answer) who has read all of the Brian/Kevin books can't recall any mention of Sonic Tanks in those books either.
The only other known appearances of this technology are in other video games that all seem to be expanding on the sonic weaponry introduced by the David Lynch film.

There are only three references to "sonic" anything in the six original novels. Two references to people using sonic sensing technology to see through rock and one cleaning tool, presumably like this thing

Aside from whether or not the fandom likes them (I like some of Brian and Kevin's "Dune" books), I've read them all and can't recall any mention of any Sonic Tanks.

Sonic tanks also appear in the video games Dune 2000 (the remake of Dune 2) and Emperor: Battle For Dune (the sequel to Dune 2000). These games are loosely based on the look and feel of the Lynch movie, but do not follow the plot of the books or movie.

@Robyn They also appeared in a Dune-themed April Fools' event in the game War Thunder.

Since Sonic weaponry was only invented by David Lynch as an alternative to the wyrming ways (hand to hand combat skills) of the sisterhood which Paul teaches the Fremen in the books because he could not envision "kung fu fremen jumping around in the desert" - they are only present in the Lynch movie and adaptions expanding on the movie (like the Dune games drawing inspiration from the movie)
